# Looking for an alternative browser that doesn't leak memory nor my data, and is secure

Tags: web-browser

lately I have been using Firefox. It works rather well, but given my browsing habits (I never close down Firefox, I rarely reboot my macbook) I end up with an instance of Firefox that eats up 2/3 GB of RAM.

This is obviously unacceptable, and Firefox is well known to have memory leaks here and there. On the long run, "here and there" bogs down my machine and I need to close it down (when it doesn't crash) and restart it, and since I don't save things in the browsers (password, forms ecc) I need to re-login everywhere. :(

On the other hand I am concerned with Chrome and Safari, since I don't want history on my browser, nor want to provide data about a person (me) to third parties (via cookies, history, habits, tracking, whatever). So no Safari, no Chrome.

I don't know about Opera, but I never used it: I have always been curious, and I will download it today.

So here's the question: given all of the previous information, which is the browser safe, not-leaking-memory and that respects my privacy that you would advise me to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you have the same concerns about Safari/Chrome with Firefox or Opera?

Comment: Firefox I can control, via several controls I know well. So far I haven't used Opera, but they have clear statements about what they use and what they not (the fact they respect them is a different matter entirely).

Comment: You don't even need to set Incognito mode in Chrome; just go into the settings and shut everything off.  You can even forego assigning a Google account to Chrome if you like.  If you really want a pristine browser, use a copy of VirtualBox and snapshot the OS, do your browsing there, and revert to the snapshot upon shutdown.  Or use a browser like `elinks` or `w3m`.

Comment: while elinks and w3m are incredibly useful on remote machines they are not really useful on a variety of websites which employ something more than html+css (think javascript, for example). On the other hand, the idea of snapshotting and reverting a VBox VM is not so bad :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome is a data mining operation, pure and simple. It's based on Chromium, however, which is less intrusive and can use all the Chrome add-ons -- though many of those are deceptive and are actually trackers, adware and malware. This is why I stick to Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Use Safari or Chrome in Private Browsing or Incognito mode, and set Do Not Track.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A lot has changed since you posted, notably Firefox runs separate processes like Chrome. I still personally use Firefox for similar reasons listed above and that it one of the few browsers that doesn't just use some form of webkit. The one thing that has really helped with memory is using an auto-unloading plugin which removes resources used by open tabs, but keeps the tabs there. Makes it easy to come back to old tabs, makes sure scripts aren't running in the background and makes it very quick to close tabs en masse.

One downside of Firefox is that because of it's shrinking market-share more and more sites are not working correctly with it (AETNA for instance).

Comment: Can you provide links to an auto-unloading plugin?